# How to query "contains" using MongoDB Java 3?

Tags: java, regex, mongodb

I'm using Java driver 3 to work with MongoDB.
I have the following documents in a collection.

```
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("59231945aefa1a301db180a1"),
    "username" : "off",
    "trx_type" : "pair",
    "amount" : 100000,
    "note" : "testpair 2:2"
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("591d7a0b03c09b5142fb5602"),
    "amount" : 100000,
    "trx_type" : "pair",
    "note" : "2:2",
    "username" : "ok"
  }
```

I want to query for this two records.

From command line if I use this: db.transactions.find("note": /2:2/)
The following document is included.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5925e6a8aefa1a339a8c013f"),
    "username" : "oktrade001",
    "trx_type" : "pairing bonus",
    "time" : NumberLong("1495656104204"),
    "amount" : 100000,
    "note" : "22:22"
}
```

Tried several things:

This only return exact "2:2", not contains:
`Document transaction = transactions.find(eq("note", s + ":" + s)).first();`

This doesn't work:
`String note = "/" + s + ":" + s + "/";
Document transaction = transactions.find(eq("note", note)).first();`

Read about `$regex`, couldn't find example queries using this for Mongo Java 3.

Kindly help... Thank you before.

update:
so... this is the mongo command I need to do in Java driver:
`db.transactions.find({"note": {"$regex": /2:2$/}}).pretty()`
tried this in mongo command line, at got what I wanted. how to write this in Java driver 3+?
also... i need to change number 2 to a variable

Comment: Try `db.transactions.find({"note": {"$regex": /2:2/}})`

Comment: Try `Document transaction = transactions.find(regex("note", note)).first();`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for response, i need the java driver command. please refer to my update above

Comment: @Veeram this doesn't work, please refer to my update above...

Comment: Try like this: `transactions.find(regex("note", ".*" + Pattern.quote(s) + ":" + Pattern.quote(s) + ".*"));`. If you need to find the value at the very end of the string. remove the last `+ ".*"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks... i did it with this logic

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take into account that the regex pattern is anchored by default and thus *requires the whole string to match*.

Knowing that, you may easily control the position of the match:

- Start of string:

  `transactions.find(regex("note", Pattern.quote(s) + ".*"));`
- End of string:

  `transactions.find(regex("note", ".*" + Pattern.quote(s)));`
- Anywhere in a string:

  `transactions.find(regex("note", ".*" + Pattern.quote(s) + ".*"));`

One note: you will need a DOTALL modifier (an inline version of it is `(?s)`) if you need to find a match in a string that contains line breaks: `transactions.find(regex("note", "(?s).*" + Pattern.quote(s) + ".*"));`, or like this: `transactions.find(regex("note", "(?s).*" + Pattern.quote(s) + ".*", "s"));`. See the [`regex` method docs](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/?com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html). The list of supported modifiers (called *options* in MongoDB) can be [checked here](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/?com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html).

Comment: my "s" is not a string, but an int. will Pattern.quote still work?

Comment: No, you need to cast the int to a string with `Integer.toString(s)`.

Answer (score 1):

so this is what is did:

```
Document transaction = transactions.find(and(regex("note", ".* " + s + ":" + s + " .*"), eq("username", username))).first();
```

just added condition for username validation

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the right way to use regex:

`transactions.find(regex("note", "^2:2.*"));`

do not forget to escape expression if it may contain special symbols:

`transactions.find(regex("note", "^" + Pattern.quote("my * expression") + ".*"));`

Comment: thanks for response, but your answer returns exactly "2:2". what i need is like 2:2, so i'll also get "testpair 2:2"

Comment: In this case you need regex("note", ".*2:2.*")